# thrift with tornado example server raise Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, thrift

I am running the offical thrift py:tornado demo, exception was raised after the client close the transport.

example: https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/tutorial/py.tornado

```
Starting the server...
ping()
add(1, 1)
zip()
zip()
calculate(1, Work(comment=None, num1=1, num2=0, op=4))
calculate(1, Work(comment=None, num1=15, num2=10, op=2))
getStruct(1)
ERROR:thrift.TTornado:thrift exception in handle_stream
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/venv/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/TTornado.py", line 174, in handle_stream
    frame = yield trans.readFrame()
  File "/Users/user/venv/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/user/venv/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/Users/user/venv/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/user/venv/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/TTornado.py", line 141, in readFrame
    raise gen.Return(frame)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/user/venv/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/TTornado.py", line 125, in io_exception_context
    message=str(e))
TTransportException: Stream is closed
```

Is there any way to avoid this error msg or how to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

many reasons would cause `StreamClosedError`.

1. check the thrift server side, there may raise an exception.
2. after test, I found thrift `THttpServer` cannot serve Tornado client stream.
3. and, when I upgrade my tornado version from 4.4.3 to 4.5, the `StreamClosedError` disappear.

client side Thrift version: 0.10.0

Tornado version: 4.5

client side Python version: 3.5.2

System version: Ubuntu 16.04